# Binding ng-repeat object name not working

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a ng-repeat object name coming from a parent repeat (see **"dType.name"**) but the name won't bind. I've tried two methods:

(this is just a snippet)

```
**HTML:** 
(1)

    <div ng-repeat="dType in dishesTypes">                           
      <span class="small-title" class="separator">{{dType.name}}</span>                       
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,dish) in dType.name">               
          <div class="col-md-6">{{dish.dish}}</div>
          <div class="col-md-1">{{dish.type}}</div>                       
      </div>
    </div>

(2) 

    <div ng-repeat="dType in dishesTypes">                           
      <span class="small-title" class="separator">{{dType.name}}</span>                       
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,dish) in dValues[dType.name]">               
          <div class="col-md-6">{{dish.dish}}</div>
          <div class="col-md-1">{{dish.type}}</div>                       
      </div>
    </div>


**Javascript**

    menuApp.controller('appController', ['$scope',  
        function($scope){

        $scope.dishesTypes = [
            {name:'main'},
            {name:'sides'},
            {name:'desserts'}
        ];

        $scope.dValues = {main: 'main', sides: 'sides', desserts: 'desserts'};

        $scope.main = // some values from DB;
        $scope.sides = // some values from DB;
        $scope.desserts = // some values from DB;

}]);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't see where you expect dish.dish and dish.type to come from in your controller?

Comment: In your first method, if you change dType.name to dType in your inner ng-repeat, it will iterate over the properties of the object.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello Craig, I want to be able to iterate through $scope.main, $scope.sides and $scope.desserts (which are objects coming from the server and have the "dish" and "type" properties). Does that make sense?

Comment: I could easily copy-paste three times and loop through it as "ng-repeat=(key, dish) in main", and so on... but I wanted to make it dynamic in case there is a new type coming in :)

Comment: Yes, I think I see what you're trying to do now.

Comment: I can get it to work by embedding a few of your objects inside another 'model' object.  http://plnkr.co/edit/atyR2DalB1U7Ua2VRbOB?p=info

Comment: Actually, here's a better way.  Use $eval in your template.  http://plnkr.co/edit/Cow37iL2nN2L6mcDPND3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method is trying to iterate over a string.  It's not resolving the result of dValues[dType.name] a second time to give you the object you're looking for.  To work around this, you can wrap it with $eval to force another evaluation.

```
<div ng-repeat="dType in dishesTypes">                           
  <span class="small-title" class="separator">{{dType.name}}</span>                       
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="dish in $eval(dValues[dType.name])">               
      <div class="col-md-6">{{dish.dish}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">{{dish.type}}</div>                       
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Cow37iL2nN2L6mcDPND3?p=preview

You could also just call a function, and resolve everything in your controller, like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/E2vQEaVQHEOvJqIihcOD?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="dType in dishesTypes">                           
  <span class="small-title" class="separator">{{dType.name}}</span>                       
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="dish in getDishes(dType.name)">               
      <div class="col-md-6">{{dish.type}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">{{dish.dish}}</div>                       
  </div>
</div>

$scope.getDishes = function(item)
{
  return $scope.$eval($scope.dValues[item]);
}
```

Comment: Hello Craig, I think that's what I did (voted it up). Do I need to do something else?

Comment: You can mark the answer as the 'accepted answer' and it will get a green checkmark next to it.  I'd appreciate it, thanks!